# how to get contacts from google contacts programmatically in android

Tags: android

i am using contacservice class and i set the usercredentials of my gmail account
and i want to get the contact from the google contacts for that my code as follows

```
ContactService myservice=new ContactService("ex-app-1.0");

  myservice.setUserCredentials("username","password");

  URL url=new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/xxx@gmail.com/full");

ContactFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
```

but i got an exception like this in logcat

```
03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

ComponentInfo{c.b.p/c.b.p.ContactsBackupActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at c.b.p.ContactsBackupActivity.onCreate(ContactsBackupActivity.java:128)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

03-16 12:24:49.217: E/AndroidRuntime(1013):     ... 11 more
03-16 12:29:49.329: I/Process(1013): Sending signal. PID: 1013 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Use this Links..


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716134/import-contacts-from-yahoo-gmail-in-android